# Handle telegram webhook data in python 3

Tags: python-3.6, chatbot, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, py-telegram-bot-api

I made chatbot using this framework [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) and set webhook to my chatbot in Telegram. I use CherryPy for this. Everything works fine. But I can't handle data which user sends to my bot. I just get notification that user send something. How I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. Just found variable in my code that responds for json. Here's my code:

```
class WebhookServer(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    if 'content-length' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                    'content-type' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                    cherrypy.request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
        length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['content-length'])
        json_string = cherrypy.request.body.read(length).decode("utf-8") <-- this one responds for json from webhook
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)

        global jsonObj

        jsonObj = json.loads(json_string)

        print(jsonObj)

        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)
```